# How could I implement a hanging paragraph style in this environment?

Tags: memoir, paragraphs

I would like to implement a hanging paragraph style in the `\readprose` environment.

I have tried with `\everypar{\hangindent0.8cm\hangafter=1}` but it gives me error on compilation.

EMV:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{alltt} 
\newfontfamily\lmodernR{Latin Modern Roman}

\newenvironment{readprose}
{%
    \begin{alltt}\small\linespread{.5}\lmodernR}
    {\end{alltt}
}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{readprose}
        En los días futuros estará firme
        
        el monte de la casa del Señor, 
        
        en la cumbre de las montañas, 
        
        más elevado que las colinas.
        
        
        
        Hacia él confluirán todas las naciones, 
        
        caminarán pueblos numerosos y dirán: 
        
        «Venid, subamos al monte del Señor, 
        
        a la casa del Dios de Jacob. 
        
        
        
        Él nos instruirá en sus caminos 
        
        y marcharemos por sus sendas; 
        
        porque de Sión saldrá la ley, 
        
        la palabra del Señor de Jerusalén». 
        
        
        
        Juzgará entre las naciones, 
        
        será árbitro de pueblos numerosos. 
        
        
        
        De las espadas forjarán arados, 
        
        de las lanzas, podaderas. 
        
        
        
        No alzará la espada pueblo contra pueblo, 
        
        no se adiestrarán para la guerra. 
        
        
        
        Casa de Jacob, venid; 
        
        caminemos a la luz del Señor.
    \end{readprose}
\end{document}
```

I want to achieve an output like this:

```
        En los días futuros estará firme            
            el monte de la casa del Señor,          
            en la cumbre de las montañas,           
            más elevado que las colinas.            
        
        Hacia él confluirán todas las naciones,             
            caminarán pueblos numerosos y dirán:            
            «Venid, subamos al monte del Señor,         
            a la casa del Dios de Jacob.
```

Comment: your desired output shows two paragraphs with hanging indent but your input shows every line as a separate paragraph and nothing to mark the separate verses. is that really how you have the input or are the blank lines just an artifact of copying to this site?

Comment: also what is the intention of `alltt` here? `alltt` makes everythng `\ttfamily` (monospace) but you enter that environment then switch back to latin modern (which is the default font in luatex had you not set any fonts at all.)  Do you want the verses set in a monospace font?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have the entry as it appears in the EMV (single space to separate each line and double space to separate each group of verses). I want each group of verses with indentations from the second line and with the Latin Modern font. If there is a better way to achieve this there is no problem in changing the environment settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't want to change fonts so `alltt` is not the right enviornment, I think you are using it to get access to `\obeylines` to avoid writing `\\`  at the end of each line, so something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}


\newenvironment{readprose}
{%
 \small
\addtolength\leftskip{.8cm}%
\def\par{%
  \ifvmode\everypar{\hspace*{-.8cm}\everypar{}}\endgraf\ifdim\lastskip=0pt\vskip\baselineskip\fi
  \else\endgraf\fi}%
\obeylines
}
{\par}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{readprose}
        En los días futuros estará firme
        el monte de la casa del Señor, 
        en la cumbre de las montañas, 
        más elevado que las colinas.
        
        Hacia él confluirán todas las naciones, 
        caminarán pueblos numerosos y dirán: 
        «Venid, subamos al monte del Señor, 
        a la casa del Dios de Jacob. 
        
        Él nos instruirá en sus caminos 
        y marcharemos por sus sendas; 
        porque de Sión saldrá la ley, 
        la palabra del Señor de Jerusalén». 
        
        
        Juzgará entre las naciones, 
        será árbitro de pueblos numerosos. 
        
        De las espadas forjarán arados, 
        de las lanzas, podaderas. 
        
        No alzará la espada pueblo contra pueblo, 
        no se adiestrarán para la guerra. 
        
        Casa de Jacob, venid; 
        caminemos a la luz del Señor.
    \end{readprose}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is one best solution. Thanks a lot!